# determine which mac/ip address(es) are connected to a switch port

Tags: networking, switch

i have some linksys srw 2024 switches. id like to know which device(s) is connected to which switch(port).

how could this be done...?

the best would be a tool that scans a ip range, sees the switches and gives me a graphical representation of the network.

Comment: Obvious question, but that appears to be a managed switch with a web UI - have you looked in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the switch's web interface doesn't provide this feature, and you want to do things on the console, Randy's host-side `nmap` and `arp` commands will get you started.  Here's the next step.

First, [get to a useful switch console](http://www.crc.id.au/real-console-on-linksys-srw2024-switch/) instead of the default menu following these instructions (this is the stripped-down version; see the post for more details):

1. Connect to the device (telnet, SSH) and login.
2. When you get to the main menu, press Ctrl-Z.  This should get you to a `>` prompt.
3. Launch the `lcli` application.  Login again.
4. From here you have a Cisco-ish style console.

The linked post indicates the `lcli` app does vary a bit from the "Cisco method", but not too much.  To [get the arp table](http://www.joshgentry.com/cisco/cisco-quick-tips.php), you'll want to get into [enable mode](http://www.joshgentry.com/cisco/cisco.htm#sect2.1), and run:

```
Router#show arp
```

Comment: I didn't know about lcli, that's a great tip!

Answer (score 0):

Use nmap's ping sweeper to get the IP address of each machine:

(assuming your LAN is 10.1.1.0/24)

```
nmap -sP 10.1.1.1-255
```

As for mac address, you can use arp to get that per host:

```
arp 10.1.1.111
```

As for the switch port connection, you're going to have to get to your switch console or interface to show the arp table for that switch.